# Check which Radio Button is checked in C#, with dynamically created radiobuttons

Tags: c#, visual-studio, radio-button

I can't find any solution or hint on this problem. Problem described after this code.

I must create one picturebox and radiobutton for every folder found on a specific path:

```
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string pathtocircuits = "../../tracks";
            string[] allfiles = Directory.GetDirectories(pathtocircuits, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
            int imgx = 387;
            int imgy = 153;
            int radx = 428; 
            int rady = 259;
            String track = "";
            String pici = "";
            String pic = "pictureBox";
            String rad = "radiobutton";
            String radr = "";
            String picr = "";
            
            foreach (String file in allfiles)
            {   
                track = Path.GetFileName(file);
                pici = "../../tracks/" + track + "/p_" + track + ".png";
                picr = pic + element.ToString();
                radr = rad + element.ToString(); 
                PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
                pb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(imgx, imgy); ;
                pb.Image = Image.FromFile(pici);
                pb.Width = 100;
                pb.Height = 100;
                pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                pb.Name = picr;
                Controls.Add(pb);

                RadioButton rdo = new RadioButton();
                rdo.Name = radr;
                rdo.Text = "";
                rdo.Tag = track;
                rdo.Location = new Point(radx, rady);
                this.Controls.Add(rdo);
                

                element += 1;
                imgx += 110;
                radx += 110;
            }
            
        }
```

With this part I get to create the elements I need (it works).

**My problem is when I press a button to reach Form2. How can I check which radiobutton is selected and store its Tag value in a String?**

```
for(int i = 0; i<element; i++)
            {
                if( ??? .Checked == true )
                {
                     globalstring = ??? .Tag;
                }
            }
```

If I try to use the name of a created radiobutton instead of a ??? it gives me an error like 'element ??? does not have a Checked or Tag attribute'

Answer (score 0):

Add method below

Add to For loop : rdo.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(radioButton_CheckedChanged);

```
       private void radioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RadioButton button = sender as RadioButton;

            string name = button.Text;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

RadioButtons as any other control are stored in the Controls collection of their container. If you add them directly to the form you can retrieve them using this code.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var radio = this.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Checked);
    if(radio != null)
    {
        string tag = radio.Tag.ToString();
        .....
        // Form2 = new Form2(tag);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The radiobuttons are added to a same group by default, so you can get the checked radiobutton as followed.

```
List<RadioButton> radioButtons = this.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().ToList();
RadioButton rb = radioButtons
        .Where(r => r.Checked) 
        .Single();
string tag = rb.Tag.ToString();
```